# Show version number on Blazor WASM core Hosted from CLI

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-webassembly

So I am able to set the version in CSProj and show it on my Blazor APP. But when I try to dotnet build and set the version from the CLI. EG:

```
dotnet build ./src /p:Version="1.2.3" /p:InformationalVersion="1.2.3-qa" --configuration Release
```

I have tried plenty of different commands and without luck

in blazor wasm I am adding a version service that just takes the value of:

```
Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().
    GetCustomAttribute<AssemblyInformationalVersionAttribute>().
    InformationalVersion
```

But I just get: "1.0.0"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found out I had put it on the build and not publish....

dotnet **publish** ./src /p:Version="1.2.3" /p:InformationalVersion="1.2.3-qa" --configuration Release